# How to Retrieve the data stored in a Table and load it into a Combo box in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox

I am creating an application for which I need to retrieve data stored in database table and load it into an combo box in Visual Studio 2008.

Consider there is only one column of data like following:

```
123
456
789
123
456
789
```

and I want to retrieve and load the same into an combo box in the same manner where each number is stored as separate items and not as a single string. How to do it? Please Explain in details.

So far I have done

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\My Documents\mydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
```

Now when the form loads the combo box should automatically consist of the items that are in the database column. How to do it?  Please explain everything in detail. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In a good question, you should show the part of code you're having trouble with. Thus, add in details about how you're creating the combo box, in what kind of data structure you've stored the results of the DB query and why you cannot add the latter to the former.

Comment: Consider a  empty form with only an combobox. And an sql database with an table name no_tb. In this table there is only one row, with 10 numbers. Now i want to load this data in the table to the combobox when the form loads. I wanted to upload images, but i need more reputation so i couldn't...

Comment: Just telling you the ways you can perfect your questions in the future, since you're a new user, that's all. The better the question, the better the answers. See [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\My Documents\mydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")

    connection.Open()
    Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT column1 FROM table1", connection)

    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim dataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = sql
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "column1")
    Dim datTable As DataTable = dataSet.Tables("column1")
```

Then You can store the data from the data table into combobox as below.

```
for x = 0 to datTable.rows.count - 1
  Combobx.Items.Add(datTable.rows(x).item("column1"))
next
```

Comment: Hey man thanks a lot. This code worked perfectly well. Thanks a million.